# JavaFX Populating TableView by using ComboBox selction

Tags: sqlite, javafx, combobox, tableview

I am trying to populate a TableView called `CustomerTableView`using a ComboBox called `ComboBoxSelectCustomer`. Basically the user selects a customer from the list of customers inside the ComboBox and than the TableView will populate with data that matches that customer's name. I have multiple tables in an SQL file with each customer but for some reason when I select a customer name from the combobox, nothing happens on the TableView, it just remains empty. There are no errors or any issues with the code, I just think that the way it is setup is whats causing the problem. Please review my code and advise me on how I can set these methods up in a better way to have the ComboBox trigger an SQL statement to populate the TableView

//MainController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package supremeinkcalcmk2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 */
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> ComboBoxSelectCustomer;
    @FXML
    private TableView CustomerTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<BaseColor, String> BaseColor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<BaseColor, String> Price;
    Connection connection;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

        //Customer combo box
        ComboBoxSelectCustomer.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(ComboBoxSelectCustomer.getValue()));
        buildDataComboBox();
        buildDataTableView();

    }

    public void buildDataTableView() {
        //viewtable db connect
        ObservableList<BaseColor> dataCustomerViewTable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        BaseColor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BaseColor, String>("BaseColor"));
        Price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<BaseColor, String>("Price"));
        connection = SqlConnection.CustomerConnection();
        try {
//problem
            String SQL = "Select BaseColor, Price FROM " + ComboBoxSelectCustomer.getValue();
            connection = SqlConnection.CustomerConnection();
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                BaseColor BS = new BaseColor();
                BS.BaseColor.set(rs.getString("BaseColor"));
                BS.Price.set(rs.getString("Price"));
                dataCustomerViewTable.add(BS);
            }
            CustomerTableView.setItems(dataCustomerViewTable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    //combobox sql connection and fill data
    public void buildDataComboBox() {
        ObservableList<String> dataComboBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        connection = SqlConnection.CustomerConnection();
        try {
            String SQL = "Select Name From CustomerList";
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                dataComboBox.add(rs.getString("Name"));
            }
            ComboBoxSelectCustomer.setItems(dataComboBox);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error Building ComboBox Data");
        }
        if (connection == null) {
            System.exit(1);
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
        }
    }

    public boolean isDbConnected() {
        try {
            return connection.isClosed();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the call to `buildDataTableView` in the event handler? Also, don't suppress the exceptions in `buildDataTableView`: if something goes wrong there is no way for you to know what.

Comment: You try to do something on a change in the `ComboBoxSelectCustomer` yet the only listener you add is the `onAction` listener,which doesn't do what you want and potentially replaces a listener added from the fxml.Also the only connection to the database that is obviously established in the code seems to be done in the `initialize` method.Where do you actually react to any user interaction with loading data from the database?Also directly accessing the fields of `BaseColor` to modify the properties gives me headaches.Have you implemented the methods neccessary for `PropertyValueFactory` to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created a setOnAction event on `ComboBoxSelectionCustomer` which allowed the TableView to populate whenever the user changes options on the ComboBox.

```
    ComboBoxSelectCustomer.setOnAction((event) -> {
});
```